# c# Setup Project - Make sure .EXE runs prior to MSI?

Tags: c#-4.0, setup-project

I'm using a C# setup project which includes some pre-requisite software. These pre-req's appear to only get installed by the EXE and not the MSI (both EXE and MSI are created when I build my setup project.)

I can't always trust that my users will bother running the EXE as opposed to the MSI, so is there a way to force it? Perhaps some options:

- My app needs Sql CE 3.5 SP2 - Is there a way that I can have the MSI install this instead of it only being installed in the EXE?
- Is there a way to make my MSI detect when it's launched by the user instead of launched by the EXE?
- Can I have my MSI launch the EXE installer as part of it's install process?

Comment: The setup.exe is only there to ensure that the target machine has the right version of MSI. What is the real problem?

Comment: If the user runs setup.msi, SQL CE will not be installed. If the user runs setup.exe, then SQL CE WILL be installed. I can't prevent the user from ignoring the EXE and running only the MSI. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Visual Studio setup project. However, commercial setup authoring tools offer multiple solutions:

- handle prerequisites from the MSI installation UI instead of using an EXE
- embed the MSI into the EXE so you have only one setup file
- configure the EXE to set a custom MSI property and create a launch condition based on that property; this way the MSI will stop if the property was not set by the EXE

If you want to continue using Visual Studio, a solution would be to create a launch condition for Sql CE 3.5 SP2. This way the installation will stop if Sql CE 3.5 SP2 is not installed.